# Where is my dividend?

Tags: stocks, dividends, dividend-paydate

I have been holding a stock "ASG" for almost one year. By the  [ASG Dividend History,](http://www.dividend.com/dividend-stocks/financial/closed-end-fund-equity/asg-liberty-all-star-growth-fund-inc-com/#payout-history-table) I should get some dividend.  I checked my account on TD Ameritrade, it only shows my share amount. But where can find the dividend amount?

Comment: Did your number of shares change post-dividend? You might be setup as a DRIP.

Comment: Did you look at your detailed transaction history for the periods that include the dividend payout?

Comment: oh, I found it under history and statement if I set view date range. But how to get the dividend?

Comment: History & Statements
Transactions
Select dividends
Time range
Done

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your dividend should show up in one of a few methods:

(1) Cash in your trading account
(2) A check mailed to you
(3) A deposit to a linked bank account
(4) As additional new shares in the stock, as the result of a DRIP setup.

Comment: Although the question was about a particular instrument paying cash dividend I should also add that companies sometimes pay dividends in either stock or stock options (usually as warrants in the UK) for internal corporate reasons so even if you don't have a DRIP set up a dividend could automatically increase your stock quantity.